# Regex only numbers and hyphen(-),plus(+),hyphen and plus are optionally

Tags: jquery, asp.net, regex

Regex only numbers and hyphen(-),plus(+)... hyphen and plus are optionally. hyphen should be middle of numbers . and plus should be start. and 8-13 characters should be

**it should accept the following**

0484-760393

+917679888

5756765757

**it shouldnt accept following**

-564654656

76+34543543

5252235 (min 8)

32525354567865(max13)

please help me

thanking you....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^[\+]?(\d\-?){8,12}\d$
```

I could break it down for you but it doesn't sound like you care much about the implementation or you would have written it yourself =)

Comment: it works like a charm.... thanks a lot ... its much complicated one . i tried a lot... any way one again thanks..

Comment: This will actually accept even strings that are 25 characters long.

Comment: Maybe it's actually what you want. Your question was very unclear. I just noted that a string like `+1-2-34-56-78-91-2-34` or `1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-1-2-3-4` will be accepted. It's much longer than 13 characters but there is still the maximum of 13 digits. If you're working with phone numbers it probably makes sense. Next time try to specify what you want better.

Comment: ya .. u r correct.. i dindnt notice that.. multiple hiphen will be accepted.